# Linux bash how to get rid of the last \r char in string value of a shell variable?

Tags: string, bash

On centos 8.4 (same on centos 7.8 and ubuntu 20.04),

This is the script,

```
#!/bin/sh
NAP_COMMON_CURRENT=$(pip freeze | grep nap-common | awk -F = '{print $NF}' | tr -d '\012')

echo "=== check 1 ($NAP_COMMON_CURRENT) ==="
echo $NAP_COMMON_CURRENT | od -x
echo ""
echo "=== check 2 ==="
echo $NAP_COMMON_CURRENT | tr -d '\012' | od -x

NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED=$(echo $NAP_COMMON_CURRENT | tr -d '\012')
echo ""
echo "=== check 3 ($NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED) ==="
echo $NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED | od -x

if [ $NAP_COMMON_CURRENT == "release-1.28.0" ]; then
    echo "NAP_COMMON_CURRENT == 1.28.0"
else
    echo "NAP_COMMON_CURRENT <> 1.28.0"
fi

if [ $NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED == "release-1.28.0" ]; then
    echo "NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED == 1.28.0"
else
    echo "NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED <> 1.28.0"
fi

if [ $NAP_COMMON_CURRENT == $NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED ]; then
    echo "NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED == NAP_COMMON_CURRENT"
else
    echo "NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED <> NAP_COMMON_CURRENT"
fi
```

This is the output:

```
=== check 1 (release-1.28.0) ===
0000000 6572 656c 7361 2d65 2e31 3832 302e 000a
0000017

=== check 2 ===
0000000 6572 656c 7361 2d65 2e31 3832 302e
0000016

=== check 3 (release-1.28.0) ===
0000000 6572 656c 7361 2d65 2e31 3832 302e 000a
0000017
NAP_COMMON_CURRENT <> 1.28.0
NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED <> 1.28.0
NAP_COMMON_EXPECTED == NAP_COMMON_CURRENT
```

I've searched the net and tried different solutions, so far only the following works,

```
NAP_COMMON_CURRENT=${NAP_COMMON_CURRENT/%?/}
```

But this solution always remove the last char from the string.

***Edit***:

Modified script:

```
#!/bin/sh
CURRENT=$(pip freeze | grep textfsm | awk -F = '{print $NF}' )
TARGET="1.1.3"

echo "=== check 1 ($CURRENT) ==="
echo $CURRENT | od -x
echo $TARGET | od -x

if [ $CURRENT = $TARGET ]; then
    echo "1. EQ"
else
    echo "1. NE"
fi

if [ $CURRENT == $TARGET ]; then
    echo "2. EQ"
else
    echo "2. NE"
fi
```

Output:

```
=== check 1 (1.1.3) ===
0000000 2e31 2e31 0a33
0000006
0000000 2e31 2e31 0a33
0000006
1. EQ
./mytest.sh: 15: [: 1.1.3: unexpected operator
2. NE
```

My initial problem is the message from the script like this:

```
./mytest.sh: 15: [: 1.1.3: unexpected operator
```

So to check if two strings are equal, we should use the single '**=**' operator, instead of the double `**==**' operator?

Copied from "man bash" on ubuntu 20.04:

```
 When  the  ==  and  != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern 
 and matched according to the rules described below under Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell 
 option were en‐abled.   The  =  operator  is equivalent to ==.  If the nocasematch shell option is 
 enabled, the match is per‐formed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.  
 The return value is 0 if the string matches  (==) or  does  not  match  (!=)  the  pattern, 
 and 1 otherwise.  Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be 
 matched as a string.


       string1 == string2
       string1 = string2
          True if the strings are equal.  = should be used with the test command  for  POSIX  conformance.   When
          used with the [[ command, this performs pattern matching as described above (Compound Commands).
```

Comment: I don't see any sign of a carriage return (variously represented as `\r`, `^M`, hex 0d, or octal 015) anywhere here. Your `od` commands are showing newlines (aka linefeed, `\n`, `^J`, hex 0a, or octal 012). The comparison is not matching because the variable starts with "release-".

Comment: Btw: `var=$(echo "Text with newline at end" | tr -d '\012')` is the same as `var=$(echo "Text with newline at end")`. You don't need the `tr -d '\012'` because `$(cmd)` removes *all* newlines at the end of `cmd`'s output. It is only in the hexdump, because `echo "$var" | od -x` inserts a new newline at the end. If you want to avoid this, use `printf %s "$var" | od -x` instead.

Comment: `var=${var%$'\r'}` in bash. `var=${var%$(printf '\r')}` in any bourne shell (`sh`, `bash`, etc).